# Ajax Accordion Panes: separate required field validators only triggered by a button in its pane

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, accordion

I have an Ajax accordion, using c# asp.net, with a few panels. In my first panel I have two required fields and have validation when a user clicks a button. Now I want more in another pane, but if I make them a required field, the button click that causes validation for them shows the message for the first panel as well.

Is there away to separate out the validators in each panel? Am I missing something completely obvious?

If any code could be helpful I will edit and include the requested code. Thank you to any advice you are able to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [`ValidationGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup.aspx)s for this.

Basically, you can set the "ValidationGroup" property on each of the validation controls that you want to group together as the same value (kind of like a CSS class).  Then, you set the "ValidationGroup" property of the button you want that group tied to as the same string.

Specifically, you'd set all of the validation controls in your `Panel1` container to the same group (so add `ValidationGroup="panelOneGroup"` to their markup).  Then, add that same attribute to the button that you want to only validate that panel.

Something like this:

```
<ajaxToolkit:Accordion ID="myAccordion" >
    <Panes>
        <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane >
            <Content>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="validator1" 
                    ValidationGroup="panelOneGroup" >
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="validator2" 
                    ValidationGroup="panelOneGroup" >
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                <asp:Button ID="button1"
                    ValidationGroup="panelOneGroup" />
            </Content>
        </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane >
        <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane >
            <Content>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="validator3" 
                    ValidationGroup="panelTwoGroup" >
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="validator4" 
                    ValidationGroup="panelTwoGroup" >
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                <asp:Button ID="button2"
                    ValidationGroup="panelTwoGroup" />
            </Content>
        </ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane >
    </Panes>
</ajaxToolkit:Accordion >
```

A detailed example on MSDN can found here: [Specifying Validation Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx)

Comment: @JoeW No problem, glad to do it.